# Reading byte array into coordinate X and Y from bitmap image?

Tags: c++, image, bitmap, coordinates, rotation

I'm trying to rotate a bitmap image clockwise 90 degree.
I've tried changing the width to height and height to width for the infoheader so when it loops it will loop the height, then width but it doesn't rotate, so i guess i need to put them into X and Y coordinate from the Byte Array Section. I've been stucked for 3 days already, so if possible, please help me! Thank you so much. Please direct me through the codes here, thank you again!

```
hfile = CreateFile(ofn.lpstrFile, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, (LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES)NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, (HANDLE) NULL );
            ReadFile(hfile, &bfh, sizeof(bfh), &written, NULL); 
            ReadFile(hfile, &bih, sizeof(bih), &written, NULL); 
            bmi.bmiHeader = bih;
            int imagesize = bih.biHeight * bih.biWidth * 3; // Allocate necessary data for image
            image = new BYTE[imagesize];
            image1 = new BYTE[imagesize];
            ReadFile(hfile, image, imagesize, &written, NULL);
            SetDIBitsToDevice(hdc, 0, 0, bih.biWidth, bih.biHeight, 0, 0, 0, 
                bih.biHeight, image,&bmi,DIB_RGB_COLORS); 

            width = bih.biHeight;
            height = bih.biWidth;
            for(int x=0; x<height; x++)
            {
                for(int y=0; y<width; y++)
                {

                    image1[(y*height+x)*3+0] = image[(y*height-1-x)*3+0]; 
                    image1[(y*height+x)*3+1] = image[(y*height-1-x)*3+1];
                    image1[(y*height+x)*3+2] = image[(y*height-1-x)*3+2]; 

                }
            }   
            SetDIBitsToDevice(hdc,height,0,width,height,0,0,0,bih.biHeight,image1,&bmi,DIB_RGB_COLORS);
            width = bih.biHeight;
            height = bih.biWidth;
            ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
            return 0;
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            return 0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we can break this down into a class that has a buffer of data and is able to "obtain" and "set" a colour at a matrix index (x,y) from such a matrix then your work will be easier.

Thus we could have in the simplest

```
setPixel( int x, int y, BYTE red, BYTE green, BYTE blue );
```

and

```
getPixel( int x, int y, BYTE& red, BYTE& green, BYTE& blue ) const;
```

Of course we could put the RGB into a single "struct".

Then you could have

```
image2.setPixel( height-y-1, x, image1.getPixel( x, y, red, green blue ) );
```

in your loop and that should rotate as long as your class is set up correctly.

Comment: Pardon my lack of knowledge, but is there no other way to do it? Setpixel and getPixel seems to be slow from what I know, from the loop, is there no other way to change the structure such that it will come out as a rotating image?

Comment: You write setPixel and getPixel. So write them to be fast. They can be inlined, of course. It just makes the code a lot simpler to follow.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Added point1 and point2 coordinates that takes in the image byte array and return x and y.

From there i figured out,

With the for loop, switching height and width over

```
image1[point2(height-1-y,x)+0] = image[point1(x,y)+0];
```

Thank you anyway!

Comment: similar to my solution, in some ways.